# Pregunta, contribución ¿o pregunta contributiva?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-propia, wiki-de-comunidad, pregunta-autorespondida

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Cuando se programa hay situaciones en las que uno se encuentra, a veces difíciles, a las que has llegado por ignorancia. A veces te cuesta encontrar una solución y cuando la encuentras quieres compartirla.

Creo que esta comunidad sería un excelente medio para exponer ese tipo de situaciones de forma que si alguien se encuentra en ellas pueda encontrar una salida.

¿Es posible hacer ese tipo de aportes a través digamos de una pregunta contributiva por llamarlo de alguna manera?

¿O compartir código que para ti es muy útil y quieres que pueda servir a otros usuarios de la comunidad?

Si esto es posible ¿qué recomendaciones me dan al respecto, cuál sería la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: si entiendo bien lo que dices: Tienes un problema das con la solucion y quieres compartirla. Pues si es correcto si crees que puede ser de utilidad para la comunidad, pues en no se que texto de SO (igual esta traducido en SOes) existe una parte en la que se alienta a los usuarios a responder a sus propias preguntas pero no se en que lugar lo leí. En como hacerlo asegurate de que si sabes la respuesta como es tu caso publiques la respuesta y la pregunta al mismo tiempo, asi evitas que alguien este escribiendo una respuesta y acto seguido aparezca tu respuesta (no siente muy bien).

Comment: Como hacerlo cuando creas una pregunta al final del formulario puedes ver un check con algo asi -> Responde a tu propia pregunta, marcas y escribes la respuesta despues publicar como una pregunta normal, la diferencia es que cuenta con una pregunta y una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Hola Cedano, gracias por el interes para contribuir, te aconsejo agregar una pregunta estructurada describiendo el problema y su respectiva respuesta. Debes buscar primeramente en el sitio si es que la pregunta ya se encuentra en el sitio. En ocasiones es bueno marcar la pregunta como Wiki de Comunidad, pero esto es decisión tuya.

Comment: @AngelAngel buenas, bienvenido de vuelta a la participación activa (se te extrañaba). Como es usual, te recomiendo que en lugar de colocar 2 o más comentarios, en su lugar publiques una respuesta. Tus ideas son buenas y valiosas y es mejor tenerlas como respuestas en lugar de comentarios.

Comment: @AngelAngel, bienvenido de vuelta a la participación activa. Yo te recomiendo que contribuyas como prefieras (siempre respetando las normas, como has hecho). Hagas lo que hagas siempre habrá quien quisiera que lo hagas de otra manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya me queda mucho más claro.

Comment: Me parece que a esta pregunta se le podría agregar la etiqueta [meta-tag:faq] y ser incluida en [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/) ¿Cómo ven? Para tratar esto sugiero la sala de chat [Acerca del indice del FAQ de la comunidad](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53106/)

Comment: @Mariano ¿por qué quitaste la etiqueta "community-wiki"? Mira este comentario en el chat -> http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35558850#35558850

Comment: @Rubén porque creo que está preguntando cómo contribuir con contenido en la forma de una pregunta autorrespondida, y que es independiente de si se publica como wiki o no. Además, ni en la pregunta ni en la respuesta se hablan de wikis.

Comment: @Mariano Gracias, borraré la edición entonces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Si! Stack Exchange [siempre ha alentado](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) a los usuarios a responder sus propias preguntas. Si tienes una pregunta la cual ya conoces su respuesta, y quisieras mantener un registro público de ese conocimiento de tal manera que otros (incluyéndote a ti mismo) puedan encontrarlo luego, es perfectamente aceptable hacer una pregunta y responderla tú mismo en los sitios de Stack Exchange.

[Para alentar a las personas a hacer esto](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), existe una casilla de verificación al final de la página cada vez que haces una pregunta. Si tienes una reputación de 15 o más y ya conoces la respuesta, haz clic en la casilla que dice **“Responde tu propia pregunta”** al final de la página de [Hacer una Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

[image: Hacer una pregunta]

Escribe tu respuesta y envía ambas, pregunta y respuesta a la vez.

Otra alternativa es regresar luego y añadir una respuesta a tu propia pregunta en cualquier momento.

También puedes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), pero debes esperar 48 horas para poder hacerlo. ¡Después de todo, alguien más puede haber propuesto una mejor solución para tu problema!

Fuente:[¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Muy clara la respuesta. ¡Gracias! ¿Podrías comentar algo sobre el contenido Wiki? ¿Convendría marcar ciertas preguntas contributivas como contenido Wiki? ¿Hay algún criterio establecido?

Comment: Que una pregunta o respuesta sea o no wiki es una cuestión ortogonal a si es autorespondida, no tiene nada que ver. Una pregunta o respuesta debe ser wiki o no ser wiki con independencia de si es o no autorespondida.