# Responder mi propia pregunta: ¿ cual es el sentido y a dónde nos lleva?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-autorespondida

Reciéntemente comencé a vincularme con esta comunidad para mayoritariamente responder preguntas y he notado muchas preguntas auto-respondidas por usuarios. Entiendo que esta es una práctica que StackOverflow permite. Mi consulta es: ¿ responder preguntas no-orgánicas ( de usuarios que nunca se hicieron esa pregunta que estamos autorespondiendo ) qué aporte hace a la misión que StackOverflow persigue ?

Comment: esto no responde tu pregunta? https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1422/324 (no quiero cerrarla a menos que estes preguntado otra cosa)

Comment: No. Eso es la explicación de porqué StackOverflow admite una auto-respuesta pero yo busco debatir cual es el sentido de auto-responder una pregunta que nadie hizo. Es una pregunta abierta como marca el tópico.

Comment: pero ahi se aclara que la idea es compartir conocimiento.. por ejemplo conocimiento que acabas de descubrir... o si nadie pudo responderte, y lo descubriste solo, agregar ese nuevo conocimiento... capaz nadie la hizo hasta ahora, pero en el futuro a alguien le sirva...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pregunta, contribución ¿o pregunta contributiva?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422/pregunta-contribuci%c3%b3n-o-pregunta-contributiva)

Answer (score 10):

> ¿cual es el sentido y a dónde nos lleva?

El sentido es el mismo del que se tiene al responder una pregunta que no sea propia, ¿por que debiera ser distinto el sentido? ¿y a dónde nos lleva? a generar más contenido útil para nuestra comunidad.

**Uno de los consensos más fuertes en la comunidad, es que aquí se juzga el contenido y no al autor, con esa premisa, ¿por qué deberíamos ver con malos ojos las preguntas que son autorespondidas?**

Por las dudas te aclaro que soy una fundamentalista de la posibilidad de preguntar y auto responder. Trabajo en sistemas desde hace unos cuantos años, todos los días tengo problemas o cuestiones que resolver, en mi tiempo libre, muchas veces sigo pensando en problemas que necesitan una solución. Muchas veces esos problemas son preguntas del tipo ¿Cómo hacer...? ¿Por qué pasa...? etc. Muchas de esas preguntas se resuelven aquí o en el sitio en inglés, otras veces las cosas no son tan simples, y hay que investigar, leer, prueba y error, usar la experiencia, preguntar a colegas, etc. Si de ese proceso se genera conocimiento que puede ser útil a otros incluso al YO mismo pero en unos cuantos años más, ¿por que no transformarlo en una pregunta/respuesta? Claramente aquí hay un usuario que se hizo un pregunta, y que es, el mismo que la va a responder. Incluso podríamos ir más allá, ¿que pasa con las preguntas que no nacen de necesidades reales sino de la simple curiosidad del autor? ¿Que pasa si queremos hacer traducciones de preguntas del sitio en inglés que nos parezcan útiles? Nuevamente, la premisa es el contenido.

Comment: Gracias patricio, esta genial la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

Añadiendo un pequeño inciso a la excelente respuesta de Patricio.

Si tanto a la pregunta como a la respuesta les elimináramos la *ventanita* que informa sobre el usuario que la escribió ... ¿ Tendría sentido está cuestión que nos ocupa ?

El objetivo del sitio es acumular conocimientos, bajo el formato pregunta/respuesta. El autor de la publicación es *irrelevante*. Si por cualquier motivo ambos (autor de la pregunta y autor de la respuesta) son el mismo usuario ... ¿ Importa algo ?