# ¿Cómo realizar una pregunta auto-respondida?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-autorespondida

Sé que en el sitio está permitido hacer aportes, pero...

- ¿Cuáles serian los criterios necesarios para hacerlo de forma correcta?
- ¿Se publicaría como cualquier otra pregunta? O estaria permitido ciertos factores como no poner lo que se intentó, etc

Comment: A mi parecer, cuando la pregunta es autorespondida, te podes tomar ciertas licencias. Pero de igual forma tiene que haber una pregunta completa, y una respuesta tambien completa. No basta con decir no me funciona este query y en la respuesta poner, faltaba poner el where. igual, en todo caso, siempre se puede poner la pregunta y la respuesta e ir mejorandola. Mientras la pregunta no sea un renglon, vale...

Comment: Si el sitio no hay alguna pregunta similar, y el caso sea específico y tenga una respuesta en particular, aplica autoresponder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yo diría que el criterio necesario es plantearla de forma que ayude a otra gente con problemas que sean habituales. Hay que considerar que llenar el sitio de preguntas autorrespondidas de mala calidad puede hacer más difícil que se encuentren soluciones usando la búsqueda.

Yo pondría dos métricas: que el problema sea habitual, y que la pregunta sea fácil de encontrar por quien tenga ese mismo problema.

Esto puede ser muy subjetivo. Por ejemplo tu estás siguiendo las instrucciones oficiales de un API y las interpretas de una forma que causa un error; para ti es natural pensar que otras personas pueden caer en lo mismo y puede ser interesante hacer una autopregunta de "Me sale el error X cuando uso la función Y". Pero igual es que tu interpretación de las instrucciones era errónea y el resto del mundo no se encuentra ese error.

Así que las "reglas del pulgar" que pondría serían:

- Que se piense que va a ser frecuente. O bien porque te lo parece, o porque ves la pregunta a menudo.
- Técnica, no de negocio. Indicar "Error al usar este método/clase/librería." No decir "error al hacer una programa de agenda de teléfonos", aunque uses el método. Será más fácil de encontrar.
- Específica. Indicar bien el error que se soluciona.
- Completa. A ser posible, que sea una solución que solucione el error por completo. Si un error puede tener veinte causas y solo solucionas una de ellas, igual no es tan útil.
- Con fundamento. No decir "así funciona", explicar porqué la solución funciona para que la gente entienda cuál era el problema y cómo funciona la solución.

Answer (score 8):

Una pregunta auto-respondida está explícitamente permitida en el sitio, según se documenta en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). De manera general podríamos decir que tanto la pregunta como la respuesta, deberían seguir los mismo lineamientos de estos contenidos, tanto lo que son explícitos y figuran en en centro de ayuda, en [Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y en [Respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering), así también los que surjan del consenso de la propia comunidad.

Ahora bien, entiendo tu punto y es muy pertinente que discutamos como comunidad y lo dejemos documentado, si estás preguntas pueden tener ciertas licencias.

En mi opinión, en cuanto a la pregunta, se debería seguir los lineamientos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) lo único que tal vez podríamos obviar en estos casos es la parte de *"Busca, e investiga"*, es decir, **no creo que en estas preguntas se deba necesariamente mostrar lo que se ha investigado, cuando el producto de esta investigación sea justamente la respuesta a la pregunta**. Distinto es el caso de requerir un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) si se quiere demostrar la solución a un problema, creo que resulta necesario armar un ejemplo para reproducirlo.

La anterior es por ahora la única licencia que me resulta coherente tomar en estas preguntas, e incluso lo circunscribiría a los contenidos originales, no tengo muy claro si correspondería hacer los mismo en la traducción de preguntas desde SO.

Comment: muy buen análisis. A mí muchas veces me pasa que quiero autoresponderme y tengo la sensación de "¿cuánta paja debo poner en la pregunta para que pase el corte de calidad, sin empezar a dar la respuesta?". Y la verdad es que nunca lo tengo del todo claro. Me gusta pensarlo como: "haz la pregunta no solo hacia ti, sino preparada para que cualquier otra persona pueda responderla".

Comment: Sin dudas a veces resulta farragoso y hasta a veces quita las ganas de hacerlo. Yo trato de pensar que seguramente se acceda al contenido más por por la pregunta que por la respuesta, la gente conoce el problema pero no la solución.

Comment: Interesante...sobre la ultima parte que dices creo tambien seria lo mismo si se podria mejorar la pregunta que se quiere traducir de SO

Answer (score 2):

Lo básico es, en las preguntas autorespondidas tanto la pregunta como la respuesta deben seguir los lineamientos del sitio pero el que sean bien o mal recibidas es algo difícil de generalizar por lo que quizás encuentres útil hacer una pregunta de seguimiento más específica.

Por ejemplo, podrías indicar tus áreas de interés sobre las que te estás planteando publicar una pregunta autorespondida (algoritmos, lenguajes, depuración, ...), preguntas autorespondidas similares a las que quieras publicar, si has consultado sobre el tema en el chat del sitio, si se han discutido preguntas similares en Meta

O bien simplemente se valiente, publica tu pregunta autorespondida y espera la retroalimentación habitual (votos y comentarios) luego si requieres ayuda para entender esta retroalimentación pregunta, sobre ella aquí en Meta.

P.D. Te sugiero leer [¿Qué es el efecto Meta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/65)

Relacionado

- [Las preguntas deberían de mostrar esfuerzo e investigación por parte del autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/65)
- [Pregunta, contribución ¿o pregunta contributiva?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1422/65)

Comment: Hola, solo una consulta, la ultima parte porque me sugieres leer el efecto meta?

Comment: @JuanRivera Para que estés prevenido de lo que en ocasiones pasa cuando las preguntas en Meta incluyen enlaces a preguntas/respuestas por si decides consultar sobre una publicación ya sea pregunta autorespondida o de otro tipo, ya sea propia o de otros.

Comment: @JuanRivera para completar la estupenda explicación de Rubén, puedes leer también [¿Qué es el efecto Meta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' de hecho si, lo lei, pregunte a [gbianchi](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58068315#58068315) sobre ello porque no entendia bien...entonces que deberia hacer o haber hecho?