# Consideremos no cerrar preguntas básicas, aunque no sean preguntas brillantemente planteadas

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Comenzaré diciendo que siento que soy, de cierta forma, el disidente aquí, pues sé que la mayoría de la comunidad va en la dirección contraria; pero quiero llamar a la reflexión a los miembros de esta misma comunidad sobre el hecho de que **constantemente se cierran algunas preguntas super básicas** que, en mi opinión, debieran quedar abiertas.

Insisto, me refiero a las preguntas que son demasiado simples y básicas. Algunos miembros de la comunidad parecen esperar, según los comentarios o votos de cierre, que el AP demuestre alguna investigación o esfuerzo.

Pero las preguntas son tan básicas, que la mínima investigación o esfuerzo les llevaría a la solución y esa pregunta jamás sería planteada en StackOverflow.

En mi opinión, cerrarlas es un error, sobre todo teniendo la opción de:

- Mejorarlas mediante la edición
- Ignorarlas
- Votar en contra de ellas, pero dejarlas abiertas. De hecho, la idea del sitio va en esta línea que hasta hay medallas para quién obtenga X votos positivos en una respuesta a una pregunta con X votos negativos. Acá algunas personas deciden votar para cerrar cuando simplemente podrían votar en contra. Según he podido ver, en español tenemos solamente un 3.47% de preguntas con votos negativos (5295), mientras en StackOverflow en inglés tienen un 6.95% de preguntas con votos negativos (1478262). Queries: [español](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1415953), [inglés](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1415954).

## ¿Por qué es un error cerrarlas?

Porque eso nos quita la oportunidad de dar nuestra propia respuesta a la pregunta, con lo cual estaríamos ayudando a muchos nuevos programadores que, en el futuro, mientras investigan, llegarían a StackOverflow en español a través de google o algún otro buscador, justamente al investigar sobre dicho tema.

Es más, tener una respuesta propia nos permitirá, en el futuro, cerrar esas mismas preguntas, que inevitablemente seguirán presentándose una y otra vez, como duplicadas, con lo cual aumentarán nuestras oportunidades de aparecer en resultados de búsqueda futuros.

## Las respuestas a estas preguntas son muy valiosas

Quienes tenemos la suerte de tener años desarrollando software sabemos que esta profesión pasa mucho por colocar pequeñas piezas, como piezas de lego, de forma que podamos producir una solución.

Tener respuestas a estas preguntas básicas y simples nos permitirá atraer a más y más programadores, de todo nivel, al sitio, fortaleciendo y enriqueciendo nuestra comunidad.

Yo tengo la suerte de encontrarme con estas respuestas todo el tiempo en StackOverflow en inglés, cuando estoy investigando sobre cualquier tema (incluso sobre como responder una pregunta aquí en español). Quisiera pensar que dentro de 5 o 10 años alguien va a tener esa misma disponibilidad de información en su propio idioma.

## Tampoco hacemos daño respondiéndolas, pero si que podemos hacer el bien

Vamos, nadie va a ganar un curso de programación si le decimos como crear un botón, o como centrar una imagen en HTML/CSS. De todas maneras, va a encontrar la información en el Internet, la va a copiar y la va a pegar en su ejercicio.

En mi opinión, una de las grandes fortalezas de StackOverflow es que nos da la oportunidad de explicar (a quién quiera leer) más allá de la superficie.

Yo aprovecho este tipo de preguntas como un *pretexto* para devolver un poco de lo que he aprendido a lo largo de mi carrera, en StackOverflow y tantos sitios que le precedieron en el esfuerzo por compartir el conocimiento entre colegas; les invito a ver esa misma oportunidad y relajar un poco la exigencia.

## Ejemplos:

No tengo muchos ejemplos a mano ahora, aunque este pensamiento es algo que me ha pasado muchas veces, hasta ahora, simplemente lo he dejado pasar.

Pero hoy, estaba escribiendo una respuesta para [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/456512/21) y justo cuando terminaba de escribirla fue cerrada. El motivo de cierre es que necesita detalles o aclaraciones (en mi opinión es bastante clara y puede responderse), pero el pecado del AP es no saber cómo hacer lo que está preguntando.

Dejé mi voto de re-apertura, espero encontrar, al menos, un par de personas que compartan mi forma de pensar, para no tener que tirar por la borda los minutos que invertí en escribir la respuesta.

Si alguien tiene más ejemplos, son bienvenidos. De mi parte, regresaré a dejar por aquí los que me vaya encontrando en los días por venir.

#### Edición #1

Reflexionando sobre este tema, he logrado identificar también que hay otro aspecto que está afectando al sitio, y que está, en parte, relacionado con esto, y es que esa actitud de pedir siempre que se demuestre *el esfuerzo* o que quien pregunta *está haciendo la tarea*:

## Dificulta dar respuestas canónicas

Un usuario no puede llegar y preguntar "cómo elevar un número a una potencia N en pascal".

Lo cual me parece una pregunta totalmente válida que tiene una respuesta canónica que le sirve a muchos.

Pero no, el tipo tiene que explicar que está tratando de resolver tal o cual problema, que tiene este y otro aspecto y, entonces, la única forma de responderle correctamente es tomando en cuenta todo el *ruido* que se le ha metido a la pregunta, y escribirle una rutina que, entre otras 20 cosas, eleva un número a la enésima potencia, pero también hace otros 4 cálculos y es útil solamente para esa persona en esa situación particular (y sus 32 compañeros de clase, si se molestasen en encontrar esa pregunta).

El hecho de que solo sea aceptable que un *experto* pueda escribir una pregunta de ese tipo, con auto-respuesta, limita el contenido a que haya expertos interesados en hacerlo y lo que se les pueda ocurrir, que no es necesariamente *todo* lo que se podría preguntar y responder.

Vuelvo al punto central, para mi, aquí, y es que uno de los principales objetivos de StackOverflow es construir una base de conocimiento en formato de preguntas/respuestas sobre programación en español. (la mayor, ojalá)

Y nos estamos perdiendo de esa oportunidad.

Comment: En [la pregunta que enlazas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/456512/83), así como muchas otras que se cierran, el problema no creo que sea su simplicidad, sino la falta de esfuerzo. Comparto la visión de que queremos crear una biblioteca de recursos; ahora bien, no creo que sea de recibo convertirnos en los ejecutores de las tareas de otros. Preguntas simples, sí, pero que respeten la presentación de un mínimo esfuerzo.

Comment: Tengo que estar de acuerdo con @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Se aprecia en la pregunta una falta de investigación muy clara, y para mi no es una pregunta que merezca estar abierta. En mi opinión al menos.

Comment: Considero ademas que muchas de esas preguntas quedan asi, abiertas sin siquiera una respuesta, porque son por parte de usuarios que no piensan usar realmente la plataforma.. solo buscan una respuesta.... entonces muchas de esas preguntas "basicas" son solo por falta de esfuerzo...

Comment: @fedorqui, justamente esa es mi premisa, que al haber un poco más de esfuerzo, la pregunta simplemente no existiría.  Dime, ¿qué esperas que agregue el AP a una pregunta TAN simple como esa?

Comment: @Pikoh ¿leíste mis premisas?

Comment: @gbianchi leíste la pregunta?

Comment: Lo digo porque justamente, refuerzan mis premisas. Lo que no entiendo es por qué, en preguntas tan simples, resulta tan importante que alguien demuestre esfuerzo, o que quiera ser parte de la comunidad... cualquiera de las dos simplemente haría que la pregunta no exista. Y si bien la pregunta es mala, la respuesta que se le puede dar es la valiosa. OJO que no me opongo a que se cierre la mayoría de las preguntas que se cierran, yo mismo voto por cerrar preguntas... hablo de las preguntas super básicas nada más.

Comment: Supongamos que fuera un foro de deportes y yo quiero empezar a jugar a ping pong. Si todos los usuarios preguntaran sobre cómo hacer un lifting ultrasupercomplicado para dejar la pelota muerta y evitar que blabla, ¿cómo podría yo publicar preguntas válidas? Pues enseñando qué he hecho hasta la fecha: _estoy empezando a jugar a ping pong y me doy cuenta que cojo mal la raqueta. He visto que alguna gente la coge así y otra asá, pero no veo exactamente cuál es la diferencia. Además, la postura X es complicada blablabla_. Eso yo creo que sería aceptable. En cambio _cómo se coge la raqueta_, no.

Comment: @fedorqui, francamente no le veo valor a que el AP tenga que decir que ha intentado y no le funciona. Hay cientos, quizás miles de ejemplos en StackOverflow donde eso no ocurre y son miles de _hits_ en los motores de búsqueda. ¿Es realmente más valioso que el AP tenga que agregar una explicación que no le sirve a nadie, que formar esa base de conocimiento para futuras generaciones?

Comment: Si, lei tu pregunta con atención. Por curiosidad, puedes darme algun ejemplo de los cientos de ejempos de StackOverflow de preguntas basicas que dices que hay que date de menos de..digamos, dos años?

Comment: Yo creo que lo fundamental es conseguir usuarios "valiosos". Un usuario que lo es después aceptará una respuesta, editará, comentará, etc. Si quieres generar conocimiento, ¡crea tus propias autopreguntas! Son un gran instrumento para esto.

Comment: @Pikoh, probablemente no de hace 2 años... ellos pueden darse el lujo de cerrar todas esas preguntas que se repiten y repiten, pero que ya han sido hechas antes. [Nosotros tenemos](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1416600) 152K preguntas, 166K respuestas, [ellos tienen](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1416606) 21.2M de preguntas y 31.7M de respuestas, creo que hablamos de _momentos_ diferentes en ambos sitios. Hace dos años ellos ya tenían, por lo menos, el 80% de esos números. Nosotros vamos por el mismo camino, pero muuuuuuuucho antes.

Comment: Tema complicado, lo que es simple para mi quiza no lo sea para ti, y lo q para ti sea obvio quiza para mi no. Es subjetivo, todo queda a criterio personal, es como en las elecciones, cada quien bota por el candidato que quiera y al final salga quien salga, se deben acoger todos al resultado, ya que es lo que quiere la mayoria

Comment: Claro @Japv, por eso es que digo que soy el disidente aquí :D :D :D... sé que la mayoría de la comunidad va en la dirección contraria, pero si lo saco a discusión es porque, al final, lo considero importante, más por verlo como una serie de oportunidades perdidas.

Comment: si te parece que la respuesta merece una pregunta, entonces hace una pregunta con autorespuesta. No veo porque tratar de rescatar una publicación que claramente no le interesa ni a quien pregunto. Si le interesara, aunque sea hubiera contestado alguno de los comentarios que le dejaron. Inclusive, poniendo no se que hacer. Para mi, ya decir que se hicieron 3 búsquedas en google de X manera y no se encontró nada es suficiente como para creer que se hizo un intento. Pero si no, solo parece que vienen a que les resuelvan el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi, creo que es lo que me queda, pero en realidad mi publicación no es para rescatar esa (o ninguna) pregunta en particular... si las ves por separado, poco valen la pena. Lo que pido es que demos un paso atrás para ver el bosque, no los _matorrales_. :)

Comment: Muy interesantes los números que planteas en tu respuesta a Pikoh, @jachguate. Viéndolos, parece claro que nuestra propoción de respuestas por pregunta es peor. Eso quiere decir una de las dos cosas siguientes (o ambas): que hay muchas preguntas sin contestar y que cerramos poco. También me fijé que el número de duplicados es muy bajo. Probablemente necesitemos focalizarnos en preguntas genéricas que hagan de buen atractor como canónicas y reforzar el cierre por duplicado en lugar de ir respondiendo siempre la misma cosa.

Comment: Todas las preguntas que cumple con los criterios del centro de ayuda no deben ser cerradas aunque sean básicas, si ves una pregunta básica que cumple con las normas y aun así fue cerrada, entonces deberías reportar para reabrirla

Comment: la pregunta de ejemplo fue eliminada... no hay valor ni esfuerso... cuando una persona siente que tiene la razon como yo busco la manera de rescatar las preguntas a tal punto que he logrado el apoyo de la comunidad... esto no es llegar y despotricar contra quienes voluntariamente te tratan de ayudar... simplemente sigue las normas y las recomendaciones de los usuarios y si tienes dudas estamos en el chat, saludos...

Comment: Tengo un [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/461698/listbox-python-tkinter) más de esa situación. Yo también me cuestiono si debería de haber respondido, ya que si buscas un poco puedes obtener algo de información sobre como obtener las posiciones de los items seleccionados y como remover un elemento de un listbox. Así que quizá no debí de haber respondido. No estoy seguro.

Comment: Las preguntas básicas son los cimientos de todas las complejidades del mundo, por que el pasto es verde, porque el cielo es azul, para llegar a grandes teoremas matemáticos antes se ha tenido que demostrar la existencia del 1, obviamente siempre hay gente perezosa que espera que uno les resuelva todo, pero esas cosas son fáciles de identificar, y creo en mi humilde opinión que este castillo debería estar sostenido en las preguntas clave.

Comment: Con respecto a la pregunta que planteas: "cómo elevar un número a una potencia N en pascal", le veo una grave falla. Cambiemos de perspectiva para dar un ejemplo. ¿Cómo elevar un número a una potencia N en Java?, ¿Cómo elevar un número a una potencia N en C?. Realmente lo que estaría haciendo la comunidad al responder esas preguntas es duplicar la documentación de manera no oficial. Mi posición entonces es sobre que no todas las preguntas deberían formularse. No por la sencillez de la pregunta, sino por la propia respuesta: "Lee la documentación"

Comment: Si no lees (o alguien te enseña), no vas a aprender; no es diferente a leer un instructivo para saber cómo se utiliza un aparato, o leer una receta de cocina. A lo que voy, no deberíamos crear un sitio que de como respuesta la documentación, pues la documentación ya existe para eso.

Comment: @eduardo, muchos lenguajes no tienen documentación oficial en español, es el caso de Pascal. ¿Deben todos aprender inglés primero para aprender a programar?

Answer (score 6):

> Pero las preguntas son tan básicas, que la mínima investigación o
> esfuerzo les llevaría a la solución y esa pregunta jamás sería
> planteada en StackOverflow.

Esto ya te lo he leído en alguna otra pregunta de hace algunos año, aquí en meta, y siempre me quedo grabado. No podría estar menos de acuerdo contigo. Creo que muchas veces las preguntas básicas son las más valiosas para contestar y hacerlo bien, de forma simple, concreta y clara. ¿Quién no ha tenido un colega trabajando varios años con uno, y conversando un poco, se termina dando cuenta que "hace agua" en conceptos que nos parecen básicos? Un tema súper inicial, la asignación de variables, todo los lenguajes la tienen, ¿Cuántos programadores realmente entienden que la variable no es el dato? ¿Qué solo es un nombre que apunta a una dirección de memoria? Si hiciéramos una encuesta estoy casi seguro, nos sorprendería el resultado. Además, que la persona encuentre la información en otro sitio, no garantiza tampoco que ésta sea la adecuada. En este sentido, el modelo de SOes de permanente escrutinio y control del contenido, me parece, tiene más garantía de calidad.

También me gustaría que no nos olvidemos que SOes, es una comunidad de preguntas y respuestas (no solo de preguntas), y creo que una buena respuesta no es menos valiosa que una buena pregunta.

Yo creo que las preguntas simples deberían tener cabida en el sitio, por dos razones: **(1)** pueden ser útiles y **(2)** en caso de no aceptarlas, pienso, nos obligaría a entrar en una discusión mucho más compleja: definir cuando una pregunta es simple y cuando no lo es.

Por lo qué, finalmente, la cuestión de fondo es el "Busca e investiga", si lo exigimos, el resultado de esa investigación es la respuesta que no se va a concretar. Por otro lado, quién quiera responderla de todas formas (cómo incentivamos a hacerlo), podría reformularla un poco mejor y auto-responderla, dónde podría disfrutar de cierto relajamiento en lo de "Busca e investiga" por parte de algunos revisores, tal como hemos conversado en [¿Cómo realizar una pregunta auto-respondida?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5086/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-una-pregunta-auto-respondida), situación algo paradójica, ya que en definitiva es casi la misma pregunta.

¿Y entonces, está bien responder todas las preguntas simples? En mi opinión definitivamente no, entonces ¿Dónde estaría la delgada línea roja? Yo tengo una visión más bien práctica al respecto y lo limito a:

#### Esfuerzo y valor

Una relación costo / beneficio, el esfuerzo que hace el autor de una pregunta versus el esfuerzo que implica responderla más el valor de la posible respuesta. Veamos algunos ejemplos:

1. La pregunta que has dado como [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/456512/21), en mi opinión, muestra muy poco esfuerzo del autor, mucho menor, seguramente, al esfuerzo que te tomarás para responderla. En cuanto al valor, no puedo juzgarla por que no son de las etiquetas que suelo mirar, pero ¿no se pregunto algo así antes?. Digamos que si me hubiera tocado revisarla, posiblemente la hubiera cerrado por falta de un ejemplo mínimo que sirviera para responderla.
2. Otro caso distinto es [¿Cómo seleccionar los datos solo de algunas tuplas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/456372/c%C3%B3mo-seleccionar-los-datos-solo-de-algunas-tuplas), acá se nota un esfuerzo del autor, se plantea un caso con código, un intento y una duda, es cierto que es una pregunta súper básica, pero creo que responderla me costó menos de lo que le costó al autor plantearla. En cuanto al valor, esto tal vez sea más discutible, es algo que sin duda ya se ha planteado en más de una oportunidad.
3. Y por último [¿Por qué la suma de NAs me da cero?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455460/por-qu%C3%A9-la-suma-de-nas-me-da-cero), una pregunta también básica, pero bien planteada, de un usuario habitual que acostumbra hacer preguntas, con investigación, código y ejemplos reproducibles. Además, me pareció que responderla agregaba valor al sitio, por que de hecho me recordó a mí, el concepto de [suma vacía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suma_vac%C3%ADa) y por que se debería esperar que cualquier función de suma de un conjunto vacío retorne 0.

Obviamente es todo discutible por que es un criterio totalmente subjetivo, resumiendo:

> Respondo a las preguntas básicas que demuestran un esfuerzo del autor,
> y/o son "baratas" para responder pero generan valor al sitio.

Y por último, aunque no menos importante, según mi experiencia, las preguntas simples suelen atraer respuestas simples o incompletas o no del todo exactas, lo cual es un problema peor.

Comment: Patricio, valoro mucho tu respuesta. Una disculpa si me he tardado en comentar. Hay muchas cosas en las que estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta (y siento que tu también coincides conmigo en algunas), otras no tanto. Entiendo la parte de costo/beneficio que mencionas en el apartado Esfuerzo/valor. Lo que pienso es que se puede tener una visión más amplia y ver, dentro del beneficio, lo que gana la comunidad con la existencia de una buena respuesta, y no solo lo que gana el AP (que estoy de acuerdo que muchas veces no regresará ni a buscar esa respuesta).

Comment: Obviamente, no digo que TODA pregunta deba responderse. Parte del problema es que la línea no es tan clara, y el análisis de costo/beneficio puede ayudar a diferenciarlas, solo sumando todos los beneficios. :)
Hice una edición de mi pregunta añadiendo otro aspecto importante, que no había logrado articular antes. Agradezco que leas la parte final que se agregó. Un saludo.